# How count elements in an column that are not empty

Tags: r, count

I just started with R, and i have to count elements from an column that are not empty.
For example :

```
   exampleColumn
1 "heey"
2
3 "World"
4 "how are you "
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Does "empty" mean "empty string", i.e., `""`?

Comment: Try `table`. You can find number of `""` after that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to count the strings that are not identical to the empty string (`""`), you can use:

```
sum(dat$exampleColumn != "")
```

Comment: In case "empty" might also be interpreted to mean spaces or multiple spaces, perhaps `grepl` might be useful: `sum(!grepl("^\\s+$|^$", dat$exampleColumn))` or something like that....

Comment: It is surprising how many of the really valuable suggestions reside in the comments section. Thanks @AnandaMahto

Answer (score 1):

@Sven definitely gave the right answer. If you were like me, wondering why

```
length(dat$exampleColumn != "")
```

does not work. It's because "length" counts all the TRUE/FALSE evaluations, but "sum" only sums up the TRUE values. A beginner's ah-ha moment!